# How do I check if a binary number, provided by continuous user input, is divisible by 5 each time a digit is entered?

Tags: c, binary

A user can enter 0 or 1 which gets appended to a starting number which is 0.

Each time the user adds a digit, the program should tell if the whole number is divisible by 5 or not.

**Example:**

1. First number is 0.
2. User enters '1' - complete number is '1' - the answer is no.
3. User enters '0' - complete number is '10' - the answer is no.
4. User enters '1' - complete number is '101' - the answer is yes.

I know the answer has something to do with the last remainder and keeping the last remainder, but I can't find the exact calculation or the logic or the mathematics to do it.

Comment: Did you try to think about a way? Or just tried to find the solution?

Comment: Got this question on Avaya interview

Comment: I'd just divide the number by 5 and check for a remainder.

Comment: (Seems to me that this is a pointless question for a programming test.)

Comment: That's easy. Now answer the same question if the user enters bits in reverse, from the most significant to the least significant.

Comment: @HotLicks: "I have never met a problem like that". FTFY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int old_x = 0,new_x;
    while(1)
    {
    scanf("%d",new_x);
    new_x= ((old_x<<1)|new_x);
    old_x = new_x ;
    new_x = new_x%5;
    if(!new_x)
    {
    printf("divisible by 5)
    old_x = 0;
    }
    else
    printf("not divisible by 5)
}
```

Comment: modified the code which will work for infinite number of bits

Comment: old_x is always zero, you never change it.

Answer (score 5):

In pseudocode:

```
remainder=0
while true {
    remainder = remainder % 5
    if remainder = 0
        print "divisbile"
    else
        print "nondivisible"

    remainder = (remainder<<1) + inputBit
}
```

Explanation: if a number is divisible by 5 a multiple of that number is also divisible by 5, so that part is of no interest. Since your expansion can be modeled as a multiplication by two and an addition, this can be applied to your problem. Now all you do is to multiply the remainder and add the input and check if it is divisble.

Comment: @user2247801 : 101 is divisble by 5 => remainder is 0, user enters 1 remainder becomes 1 and is not divisible by 5. if you check 1101binary = 11 decimal is not divisible by 5. Isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: In the case of user input power of 2 (`100000000...`) you potentially need an infinite remainder length.

Comment: @Alex: nope it is modulo => once the power of 2 never becomes greater than 5 (actually it does, but the maximum the mumber will be is 9. Assume the user has put in `100` (4) and now enters `1`: remainder now is `1001` (9), 9%5 (read: 9 modulo 5) is 4 and the remainder `100` (4) is stored. Rad up on modulo [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo)

Comment: @Alex: the first statement in the `while` loop limits `remainder` to one of 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. It never reaches close to infinity.

Comment: **FACEPALM** sorry, didn't mention it.

Comment: @pmg: Could you define “close to infinity”? How big does a number have to be before it is “close to infinity” but not infinity? :-)

Comment: Sure @EricPostpischil. In the context of `remainder %= 5;`, close to infinity is a `remainder` with a value of `5` :)

Comment: @pmg: Oh, well, then there is a huge problem with this code. Although the first statement in the loop limits `remainder` to four, the last statement sets `remainder` to values as high as nine. So that is very close to infinity. Surely nobody can comprehend code with such dizzying heights.

Comment: This works because any number x can be expressed as `x=5k+r` (where `k` an interger and `r` the remainder. by adding a bit `i` to the end of `x`, it gives: `x' =2(5k+r)+i` which can be expressed as: `x'=10k+(2r+i)` so the preoblem of determining if `x'` is divisible by 5 get's simplified to determining if `(2r+i)` is divisible by 5. We drop the 10k from the equation, and always know that if our number exceeds 5, we can alwasys write it as `5k+r` and drop the k.

Comment: @LefterisE: explained very well

Comment: @user2247801: no worries, but you should have left the initial comment so that [n.m.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m)'s and my comment appear in context

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that to know that if a number is divisible by 5 you only need to know the *last decimal digit* of the number. If it ends with 5 or 0 then it's divisible by 5. if it doesn't end with 5 or zero it needs an extra amount, which i call *remainder* to get there. Now given that you have the *remainder* you can reverse-engineer the *last digit* of the number. Then shift the *last digit* by 2 and add the new number the user types (*d*). Depening on *d*, you get the new last digit of the number. With that you can again see what newremainder must be added to get to the next multiple of 5.

[image]

```
int newRemainder[2][5] = {{0,2,4,1,3},{4,1,3,0,2}};
int remainder = 0;
int d;

while(1){
   scanf("%d", &d);
   remainder = newRemainder[d][remainder];
   if (remainder ==0) printf("multiple");
}
```

Comment: It will work with an infinite number of digits, since i only need the digit the user currently enters to get to the next state.